# How to set variable from connectionstring ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have question regarding ssis packages. I want to populate a variable dynamically when I run my ssis package. The variable should be the connection string of the current step/task that is being executed. For example if I have an ssis package that has two steps, the first step's connection is Server1DB1 and the second step's connections is Server2DB2. When I run the package while the first step is busy executing the variable should be Server1DB1 and once it's done and step 2 is executing the variable should be Server2DB2. I have tried finding the answer but all articles speak about changing the connection based on the variable and not vice versa. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Where's the dynamic part come into play? Task A does something on Server1DB1, Task B does something on Server2DB2

Comment: Well maybe I used the wrong word...but during runtime when each step is executing the variable gets updated/changed to the connection of the current step/task that's being executed.

Comment: I'm still not "getting it". Task A does X on Server1B1. Does the result of that execution in any way determine where Task B is performed?

Comment: No it doesn't. The reason for the variable is to be used in reporting. When Task A is busy processing the variable should be Server1DB1, I then right this variable to a table using the event handlers.
So when task A is executing, my objective is to write to the table I am using for reporting the connection that, that specific step was using.

Comment: Now we're getting closer to the problem you're trying to solve. You would like to log the connection managers a specific task uses to a table. The mechanics of how you are attempting to do this is that you have an Event Handler do something to populate a Variable and then log that to a table?

Comment: Yes that's what I would like to do. Just insert the connection that a specific step/task is using into a table.

Answer (score 1):

In a Script Task, fetch the [ConnectionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ConnectionManager.aspx) for the appropriate connection from `Dts.Connections` and then assign its ConnectionString property to a ReadWrite variable.

If your ConnectionString is set by an expression, you'll need to have the connection manager acquire the connection in order for the ConnectionString property to be updated with the expression's current value.

For example:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // Where "MyOLEDBConn" is the connection's name
        var connectionManager = Dts.Connections["MyOLEDBConn"];

        // AcquireConnection/ReleaseConnection is unnecessary if ConnectionString isn't set by an expression
        var rawConnection = connectionManager.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);

        // "User::ConnectionString" is configured as a ReadWrite variable for the Script Task
        Dts.Variables["User::ConnectionString"].Value = connectionManager.ConnectionString; 

        connectionManager.ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

The task fetches the **current** value of the connection string, based on its expression, so it needs to be executed at a point where the expression's value is the same as it was when the task being logged acquired its connection. The task could possibly be placed directly before or after each step you want to log or (better yet) in a pre- or post-execute event handler.

## An Alternative

Another approach would be to use an Expression Task to configure the connection string and assign it to a variable. Both the connection (via an expression) and your logging process could use this variable, bypassing the need to fetch the connection string from the ConnectionManager. This would eliminate the need for the above Script Task.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Just one question what is MyOLEDBConn? Which connection name do I use there?

Comment: @LiamDomingo, replace "MyOLEDBConn" with the name of your connection. You get to pick what that name is when you create the connection.

Comment: The connection is an ordinary SSIS connection created just like you would create any other SSIS connection.